# Keep only number in regex lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list that following is a sample of my list:

```
Bolt

®1421918Users

Classmates

666138Users

SixDegrees

470621Users$$

PlanetAll

AT308079Users

theGlobe

214442Users

1997
```

Now I want to keep only `number Users` from `Users` lines
For example:

```
Bolt

1421918Users

Classmates

666138Users

SixDegrees

470621Users

PlanetAll

308079Users

theGlobe

214442Users

1997
```

I tried following regex in notepad++ but not working:

```
Find What = ^.*?(\d+Users)
Replace = \1
```

and tried following regex:

```
Find What = ^(?!\d+Users).*\r?\n?
Replace = [Empty]
```

**How to fix this regex problem?**

Comment: Maybe find: `.*?([1-9]\d+Users).*` (and leave checkbox for `.` cleared)?

Comment: Are there any lines in your text that look like `4@@42#^&31415Users!34` (i.e. multiple sequences of digits, before *and* after `Users`)? If yes, how should they be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search using this regex:

```bash
[^\n\d]*(\d*Users).*
```

and replace with `'$1`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GVwGsS/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[^\n\d]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not digit and not a line break
- `(\d*Users)`: Match 0 or more digits followed by text `Users`. Capture this value in group #1
- `.*`: Match everything else till end
- Replacement is `$1` which is back-reference of capture group #1